# number sequence not working properly with actions-on-google

Tags: actions-on-google

User is passing number sequence like "1 2 3 4 5 6" in a conversation , its working fine when I am testing in API.AI output is coming as Integer without white spaces "123456". However in google home web simulator it is only retaining first digit "1" , can someone help why number sequence entity working in API.AI but not in web simulator

Comment: did you search online??

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the Intent that you're using to match the number sequence?